# do you put on a signal when you follow the driveway but changing direction

Tags: traffic, driving

[image]
I hope i'm on the right forum.
Following the green arrow, you are turning right, but following your driveway. Does the law require to put on a right signal?
What about going straight (blue arrow). Do you put on a right signal or no signal?

Comment: Did you mean a left signal for going "straight"? Not an answer for SE law, but that's what I'd do there - the one thing I'd definitely not do if going "straight" would be to signal right.

Comment: Jurisdiction would be helpful in this matter, but could you clarify if traffic on these roads would drive on the right of the road or the left, as it's hard to tell (It looks like Elliot St. Prior to the Junction is a one way, and it's hard to tell the direction of bi-directional roads.).   Either way, I doubt you will get into trouble with the law if you have your turn signal on to indicate the direction you intend to travel.  And this is a horrible intersection no matter what.

Comment: There's no legal requirement to signal in the UK regardless of the junction; it's a [rule in the Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/using-the-road-159-to-203) but not a [legal requirement](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/introduction).